# Can you annotate return type when value is instance of cls?

Tags: python, oop, pycharm, type-hinting, python-typing

Given a class with a helper method for initialization:

```
class TrivialClass:
    def __init__(self, str_arg: str):
        self.string_attribute = str_arg

    @classmethod
    def from_int(cls, int_arg: int) -> ?:
        str_arg = str(int_arg)
        return cls(str_arg)
```

Is it possible to annotate the return type of the `from_int` method?

I'v tried both `cls` and `TrivialClass` but PyCharm flags them as unresolved references which sounds reasonable at that point in time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python 3.11 there is a nicer way to do this using the new **Self** type:

```py
from typing import Self

class TrivialClass:
    def __init__(self, str_arg: str):
        self.string_attribute = str_arg

    @classmethod
    def from_int(cls, int_arg: int) -> Self:
        str_arg = str(int_arg)
        return cls(str_arg)
```

This also works correctly with sub classes as well.

```py
class TrivialSubClass(TrivialClasss):
    ...

TrivialSubclass.from_int(42)
```

The IDE shows return type `TrivialSubClass` and not `TrivialClass`.

This is described in [PEP 673](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0673/).

Comment: I had held off mentioning `Self` until mypy support was ready. There is no current mypy release that supports it, support landed after 0.991 came out. We'll have to wait for the next version before this can be used by more projects.

Answer (score 102):

Starting with Python 3.11 you can use the new [`typing.Self` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self). For older Python versions you can get the same object by using the [`typing-extensions` project](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/):

```
try:
    from typing import Self
except ImportError:
    from typing_extensions import Self


class TrivialClass:
    # ...

    @classmethod
    def from_int(cls, int_arg: int) -> Self:
        # ...
        return cls(...)
```

Note that you don't need to annotate `cls` in this case.

Warning: **mypy support for the `Self` type has not yet been released**; you'll need to wait for the next version after 0.991. Pyright already supports it.

If you can't wait for Mypy support, then you can use a *generic type* to indicate that you'll be returning an instance of `cls`:

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', bound='TrivialClass')

class TrivialClass:
    # ...

    @classmethod
    def from_int(cls: Type[T], int_arg: int) -> T:
        # ...
        return cls(...)
```

Any subclass overriding the class method but then returning an instance of a *parent class* (`TrivialClass` or a subclass that is still an ancestor) would be detected as an error, because the factory method is defined as returning an instance of the type of `cls`.

The `bound` argument specifies that `T` has to be a (subclass of) `TrivialClass`; because the class doesn't yet exist when you define the generic, you need to use a [*forward* reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) (a string with the name).

See the [*Annotating instance and class methods* section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#annotating-instance-and-class-methods) of PEP 484.

---

Note: The first revision of this answer advocated using a forward reference
naming the class itself as the return value, but [issue 1212](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1212) made it possible to use generics instead, a better solution.

As of Python 3.7, you *can* avoid having to use forward references in annotations when you start your module with [`from __future__ import annotations`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-563-postponed-evaluation-of-annotations), but creating a `TypeVar()` object at module level is not an annotation. This is still true even in Python 3.10, which defers all type hint resolution in annotations.

Comment: Is it possible to create a forward reference to cls?

Comment: @Jonatan: no, because `cls` is not a type.

Comment: @Jonatan: note that any subclass of `TrivialClass` will also satisfy the type hint.

Comment: A similar solution can be applied to class methods with `self`: `def create_something(self: T) -> T`

Comment: Then i can't use cls method anymore? Since cls has `Type[T]`, there is no suggestion for classmethod `cls.abc()` inside `from_int()`

Comment: @TomSawyer I’m not sure what you are referring to here. Are you having issues with a specific tool perhaps, like PyCharm?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes. i'm using pycharm. if i set `cls: Type[T]`, it won't suggest other class method. Already submit new question here, so i'm not sure there is the error of Pycharm or there must be another way to archive it with Python? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59226096/python-how-to-access-to-other-classmethod-while-using-generic-type

Comment: @TomSawyer I’d say that that’s a PyCharm bug. Report it to them

Answer (score 10):

From Python 3.7 you can use [`__future__.annotations`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/):

```py
from __future__ import annotations


class TrivialClass:
    # ...

    @classmethod
    def from_int(cls, int_arg: int) -> TrivialClass:
        # ...
        return cls(...)
```

Edit: you can't subclass `TrivialClass` without overriding the classmethod, but if you don't require this then I think it's neater than a forward reference.

Comment: Same issue as Noah’s answer: you hardcoded the return type of the class method.

Answer (score 7):

A simple way to annotate the return type is to use a string as the annotation for the return value of the class method:

```
# test.py
class TrivialClass:
  def __init__(self, str_arg: str) -> None:
    self.string_attribute = str_arg

  @classmethod
  def from_int(cls, int_arg: int) -> 'TrivialClass':
    str_arg = str(int_arg)
    return cls(str_arg)
```

This passes mypy 0.560 and no errors from python:

```
$ mypy test.py --disallow-untyped-defs --disallow-untyped-calls
$ python test.py
```

Comment: Much better, as it doesn't cause an error about returning TrivialClass instead of 'T' - or if you change it to return cls(...) an error about cls not being callable when using the init constructor.

Comment: You can’t now subclass TrivialClass without overriding the classmethod however. My first revision used a forward reference exactly like this.

Comment: Ah, good point! If you need to subclass, the TypeVar solution is probably better.