# How to type-hint Python 3 metaclasses?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7, type-hinting, mypy

a type warning started popping up today in some of my code after I upgraded the version of mypy that I was using. There doesnt seem to be too much literature on the subject, so hoping someone here can help me out!

I have a MetaClass defined like the following...

```
 from __future__ import annotations


 class MyMetaClass(type):                                                                                                                                

     def __new__(mcs,                                                                  
                 name: str,                                                            
                 bases: Tuple[type, ...],                                              
                 namespace: Dict[str, Any],                                                                                     
                 ) -> MyMetaClass:                                             

         # Custom code... doesnt matter
         # ...
         # ...

         return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace)
```

Today, mypy started spitting out the following error...

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "type", expected "MyMetaClass")
```

Ive tried the following iterations of the return statement, all with no success...

```
return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace)
return super(MyMetaClass, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace)
```

Any suggestions on how to get around this warning? I ended up settling for a cast... but it feels like there has to be something better.

```
return cast(MyMetaClass, super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace))
```

Comment: Just to be clear, does your class's source file begin with `from __future__ import annotations` to allow you to postpone annotation evaluation in the first place?

Comment: I strongly suspect this is actually a duplicate of [Can you annotate return type when value is instance of cls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39205527/364696). Not 100% though, can you try out the solution there?

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes it does! Will include it in the snippet above

On your other suggestion, I'm still getting an error if I use a ```T = TypeVar('T', bound='MyMetaClass')```, now its ```Incompatible return value type (got "type", expected "T")```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't annotate the `mcs` parameter, so it's impossible to know what type `super().__new__` will return.

Comment: Hey Niel -- good to revisit this. In my copy of `python 3.11.1` mypy no longer complains about the above snippet. I'm assuming whatever underlying issue has since been fixed since Sept 2019.

Comment: @wakey Oh that makes sense, they probably implicitly type the first parameter to be `type[Self]` or something.   Anyway, thanks for your question.  I had to look this up, and this was the first hit.