# Type Hint Enum @classmethod That Returns Enum Member

Tags: python, enums, type-hinting, mypy

I've written an `enum.Enum` type with a couple of members. Now I want to write a "selector" `@classmethod` that will return one of the members of the `Enum` based on arguments, and **I don't know how to type hint it properly**.

Here's what I have to far:

```py
from enum import Enum, auto
from typing import TypeVar, Type

_StringSizeT = TypeVar("_StringSizeT", bound="StringSize")
class StringSize(Enum):

    SMALL = auto()
    BIG = auto()

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls: Type[_StringSizeT], source_string: str) -> _StringSizeT:
        n_chars = len(source_string)
        if n_chars <= 10:
            return cls.SMALL
        return cls.BIG
```

The above use of `TypeVar()`, etc is me trying to follow approach of [Martijn Pieters' post in "Can you annotate return type when value is instance of cls?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39205527/can-you-annotate-return-type-when-value-is-instance-of-cls/39205612#39205612) for `@classmethod` factories, but applying them to `Enum` `@classmethod`s that return one of the enum members.

Unfortunately, mypy does not like the types of my return statements:

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "StringSize", expected "_StringSizeT")
```

This is because the properties of this `@classmethod` are different than in that post: I'm not returning an **instance** of the class, but a **class attribute**, or in enum-speak, a member.

How can I fix my method annotation here?

UPDATE: Ok, while writing this, I riffed on the advice of mypy and found that

```py
-> "StringSize"
```

is acceptable. This is a little confusing because, again, I'm not returning an instance, but I'll chalk that up to the metaprogramming machinery underneath `Enum`. **Followup: Is there a non-string-literal type annotation I could use here instead?** Through my experience, I've learned (maybe incorrectly) to dislike the string literal annotations. (Am I sacrificing anything with them?)

Comment: Note, you can just use `StringSize` as the annotation. If you are on an earlier versin, use `from __future__ import annotations`

Comment: "This is a little confusing because, again, I'm not returning an instance", yea you are. Try `isinstance(StringSize.BIG, StringSize)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Illuminating! I'd seen advice to use use that future import around, but never understood why. I would accept this as an answer if it wasn't a comment. Regarding the instance thing, yes, you're right. It confused me because in nearly all other cases, class attributes expressed this way are not also instances of that class. If anything, you'd assume it's whatever the type of `auto()` is.

Comment: The whole point of `enum` is to allow you create a class that defines a discrete number of singleton instances of that class. It uses, I assume, a bit of meta-programming magic to allow you to use that easy syntax. It's to *avoid* what existed before, which was simply a class object with a bunch of integer class attributes.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga:  You assume correctly.  :-)